# redirect traffic from 127.0.0.1:5003 to external interface

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I have an application that exposes Web Services on the loopback address 127.0.0.1:5003 so they are only available to the localhost. Is it possible to redirect traffic from there to the external interface so I can call the Web Services from other PCs on the network? I'm pretty sure this can be done by playing with the IP tables in Linux but I'm using windows 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it not take a start-up parameter to specify the listening IP/port?

Comment: It only exposes the web services to loopback by design... :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5003 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=5003 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 protocol=tcp
```

Otherwise try one of the options listed as answers to the question found here:
[Easy TCP proxy on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17990/easy-tcp-proxy-on-windows)

Comment: Just to be sure before I try, can I remove this by just replacing the 'add' in the netsh command with 'remove'?

Comment: you'd use 'netsh delete' not remove

Comment: That didn't work, still unable to connect from the external interface although I can still connect from the loopback address. Thanks for trying anyway mate.

Comment: @lachs You'll also need to unblock the firewall to allow access to 5003 if your firewall is enabled which it is by default!